# Quitar cambio de página al apretar un botón en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

mi problema es este...
Estoy usando la librería SweetAlert y creé un mensaje de alerta que aparezca como confirmación al llenar un formulario, el problema viene que al apretar el botón la alerta aparece, pero inmediatamente me cambia de pagina a la que tengo que redireccione el formulario, lo que evita que pueda siquiera ver o confirmar la alerta.

Lo que necesito yo es que al apretar el botón, salte la alerta y hasta que no apriete "Confirmar" no me redireccione a la página siguiente.

Mi código del formulario es este:

```
<form action="customer-orders.html" method="get">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Usuario">Usuario</label>
                <input id="Usuario" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre de usuario que usará">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="NombreCompleto">Nombre Completo</label>
                <input id="NombreCompleto" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre real del administrador">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña">
              </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Confirmar Contraseña</label>
                <input id="passwordconfirm" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirme la contraseña">
              </div>
                <p class="text-muted">Seleccione los permisos que tendrá el administrador</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                <select name="permisos">
                <option>Permiso 1</option>
                <option>Permiso 2</option>
                <option>Permiso 3</option>
                </select>
                </div>
              <div class="text-center">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template-outlined" onClick="return Confirmar()"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Modificar </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-template-outlined"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Ver Lista Administradores </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

El código del script es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirmar(){
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'El administrador se ha modificado correctamente',
    icon: 'success',
    confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    allowEscapeKey: false,
    allowEnterKey: false
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Al enviar el formulario con POST o GET siempre te llevará a la página que estas enviando la petición o los datos, por lo que nunca saltará tu alerta para lograr eso deverías quedarte en la página, logicamente el formulario ne se enviará a menos que lo envies mediante `AJAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedes hacer es hacer el submit desde JavaScript, en lugar de directamente en el HTML.

para hacer esto cambia el `type="submit"` por un `type="button"` (para que el boton no haga submit del form)

y en la funcion `onClick` haz esto:

```
swal({
  title: 'Guardar?',
  text: "Esto Guardara el registro!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Guardar'
}).then(()=> {

  formulario = document.getElementById(idformulario);
  formulario.submit();

})
```

En teoría esto debería ayudarte con lo que buscas